# o:inputFile optional and accept validation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I would like to add an optional "attach screenshot" field to my form, so I'm using the o:inputFile component:

```
<o:inputFile id="file" required="false" maxsize="1048576"  accept="image/png,image/gif" />
```

If I leave the field blank I get an error: Attach screenshot: Media type of file '' does not match 'image/png,image/gif'

How can I make that validation optional?

Comment: Strange, which browser are you using? This doesn't happen in latest Chrome and Firefox here. Moreover, that validation shouldn't at all run when there's no physical file. Apparently your browser sends/triggers an empty `Part` in some way. There is a theoretical workaround (just a bit of conditional EL in `accept` attribute), but I'd like to reproduce it myself first.

Comment: It happens with any browser. I can't upload a sample project here, so I opened an issue in the project.
https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/315
My environment is: myfaces 2.2.10, omnifaces 2.5.1, tomee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by unexpected behavior in MyFaces. It works fine in Mojarra which gives `null` when no file is selected. MyFaces, however, gives a non-null `Part` instance with an empty file name and a size of 0. The content type of that empty `Part` defaults to `application/octet-stream` and therefore never matches the specified `accept` attribute.

For now, your best bet is to make the `accept` attribute conditional based on the current phase ID and the file size. We want it to always evaluate during render response phase, and during other phases only when the file size is more than 0, otherwise default the `accept` to `*/*`.

```
accept="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6 
          or component.submittedValue.size gt 0 
              ? 'image/png,image/gif' 
              : '*/*'}"
```

I will fix this for upcoming OmniFaces 2.6 as per [issue 315](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/315).

Comment: As i just came across this thread while searching for some info: the file extensions (e.g. "image/png") seem to be case sensitive. If i try to upload a file named test.PNG my validation fails. Does this work as intended?
 My Omnifaces Version is 2.6.2.